# String encoding and decoding from possibly latin1 and utf8

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, latin1

I recently stumbled upon a MySQL database that was encoded using Latin1 and was rendering when viewed on a browser question mark symbols. To fix this we changed the encoding of the DB to utf8 and the Collation to utf8_general_ci on all of our tables, but the data already stored was still showing up with question mark symbols, all of the storing and polling of data from mysql to the browser was done by php i made sure utf8 was used on php as well and even ran set names utf8 as many people suggested online, the problem is that now I ended up with weird characters such as ÃƒÂ‘ on strings we knew didn't had them.

Examples of data

Stored:

**EMMANUEL  PE\xc3\u0192\xc2\u2018A GOMEZ PORTUGAL**

Rendered:

**EMMANUEL  PEÃƒÂ‘A GOMEZ PORTUGAL**

Proper:

**EMMANUEL  PEÑA GOMEZ PORTUGAL**

---

Stored:

**Luis Hern\xe1ndez-Higareda**

Rendered:

Luis Hernández-Higareda

Proper:

**Luis Hernández-Higareda**

---

Stored:

**Teresa de Jes\xc3\u0192\xc2\xbas  Galicia G\xc3\u0192\xc2\xb3mez**

Rendered:

**Teresa de JesÃƒÂºs  Galicia GÃƒÂ³mez**

Proper:

**Teresa de Jesús  Galicia Gómez**

---

Stored:

**DR. JOS\xc3\u0192\xc2\u2030 ABEN\xc3\u0192\xc2\x81MAR  RIC\xc3\u0192\xc2\x81RDEZ GARC\xc3\u0192\xc2\x8dA**

Proper:

**DR. JOSÃƒÂ‰ ABENÃƒÂMAR  RICÃƒÂRDEZ GARCÃƒÂA**

Currently I'm using python to get the data from the DB, I'm trying to normalize to unicode utf8 but I'm really lost, thats as far as I'm getting here, I need to convert what currently shows up as weird characters to readable text as shown above.

what am I missing here? is the data on unrepairable?

Functions
https://gist.github.com/2649463

**Note:**
of all of the examples there's 1 that is properly rendering (left there so consideration is taken if any advice is given on how to fix this )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you attempted to insert characters which cannot be represented in `latin1` into columns stored under that character encoding, those characters would have been irreversibly replaced with `?` - information has been lost: your only option is to reinsert/update the data now that the column is stored in `utf8`.

However, some of the data in your question doesn't make a great deal of sense.  For example:

> Stored:
>
> **EMMANUEL PE\xc3\u0192\xc2\u2018A GOMEZ PORTUGAL**

Are you trying to show the *bytes* or the *characters* that are currently stored?  Either way, one of the `\u` or `\x` escape codes is meaningless.

You say that the original data was encoded as `latin1`; in that character set, the **Ñ** character is encoded as `0xd1`.  You say that you then converted the data to `utf8`, which would have changed the encoding of that character to the two-byte sequence `0xc391` (which explains the `\xc3` you show as being stored, above; however, it is not clear how the second byte `0x91` turned into the sequence `\u0192\xc2\u2018` in your snippet*).

I suspect that the data has in fact been through some further conversions, perhaps between that which is currently stored and whatever means you are using to view such storage.  You would be well advised to first ascertain *exactly* what is stored within your database:

```
SELECT HEX(my_column) FROM my_table WHERE ...
```

Once that has been determined, you will be better able to understand what conversions (if any) need to be employed on your stored data to make it `utf8` and what undesirable conversions (if any) are taking place during storage and retrieval operations.

---

<sup>* Having now read Thanasis Petsas's answer, I realise he's figured out that you appear to have decoded properly `utf8`-encoded strings as `latin1`, encoded the resulting characters using `utf8` and then decoded those bytes as `latin1` again.  This does indeed produce the character sequences you've shown, but it is still nevertheless necessary to understand what is actually stored and what is due to conversions during retrieval.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
print str.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
```

an example using `ipython`:

```
In [49]: a=u'Teresa de Jes\xc3\u0192\xc2\xbas Galicia G\xc3\u0192\xc2\xb3mez'

In [50]: a=u'Teresa de Jes\xc3\u0192\xc2\xbas Galicia G\xc3\u0192\xc2\xb3mez'

In [51]: print a
Teresa de JesÃƒÂºs Galicia GÃƒÂ³mez

In [52]: print a.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
Teresa de Jesús Galicia Gómez
```

This is a *"mis-encoded"* utf-8..

Comment: Tried doing that but I think I'm missing something, I can know see how the data got "mis-encoded" how would I go about detecting the chain of encoding and decoding that I have to use? here is a link to a gist showing I got something wrong at least with my example strings https://gist.github.com/2654309